# Modal dialog not visible

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Trying to create modal dialog (CDialogEx) from modeless window form :

```
void CMainWindow::OnPushButtonClicked ()   
{   
    InputDialog dlg;
    int r= dlg.DoModal();
    AfxMessageBox("do modal is done");
}
```

Got no visible input dialog, but DoModal procedure did not returns. Why dialog is not visible?

Comment: What do you mean by "modeless window form"?

Comment: We need more information.

Comment: Did you set the "Visible" property of the dialog template? Open the dialog resource in the resource editor, right-click Properties, and look through the properties.

Comment: What happens if you run your code from Debug mode? Do you receive any Assert messages?

Comment: Yes problem was with "visible" property. But then I have question why this dialog was showing normally when I have created it in CWinThread::InitInstance ?